# 2015 MacBook Pro 15” Cooling fans seem to be spinning in opposite direction?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, cooling

I just recently placed a new battery and speakers into a 2015 15” MacBook Pro. To do this I had to take out the entire logic board. Obviously, the fans have to be in the correct position as you can only orientate them one way when installing them. However, cool air now seems to be flowing out of the bottom side grills, and is being sucked in from the hinge area. The airflow has somehow been reversed. I have no idea how this is possible, but it is affecting the temp of the cpu. If anyone has any recommendations on what to do, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: My limited understanding of motors tells me this could happen if wires were swapped. I can't imagine there are any reversible plugs on the cooling fan, though.

Comment: @EzekielElin there’s only one connector pin per fan, but I thought the same thing as first.

Comment: Please re-post your comment as an Answer. It's perfectly acceptable to answer your own Question, and because Answers are indexed, the solution will be findable by others.

Answer (score 1):

Did a SMC reset about 5 times and it seemed to fix to issue.